# Can/should I hide my logic in a Solana program?

Tags: solana-program

I know that binaries of programs are available for everyone cause they are on chain but I could not find into how to get these binaries.

On ETH we can get binaries from etherscan.

So my question is : what if I’ll make some encode/decode functions in my contract will anyone be able to know these features and the coding key?

Example : user use my program's instruction handler with data : “fgh, and my program decodes this to “one”

Will be anyone able to get my decode algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

To store private keys or rely on a fancy encoding to obfuscate secrets is not a great idea.

It is safe to assume data and code deployed to a blockchain can be read and understood by anyone with the right skills and resources.